# engage children ... for their empowerment

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Renowned Chinese singer and actor Wang Yuan was appointed UNICEF
>   newest ambassador for children today, just days ahead of World
>   Children's Day. In his new role, the young ambassador, who just turned
>   18, will use his widespread influence to **engage** children and young
>   people **for** their **empowerment** to strive to be best they can possibly
>   be.

I don't understand "engage children ... for their empowerment".

[engage sb in sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/engage-sb-in-sth)

> If you engage someone in conversation, you start a conversation with
>   them.

I think it isn't this meaning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is kind of a poorly-written mess, so it's little wonder it's hard to understand.  Understanding the meaning of these two separate terms helps:

To "engage" someone can variously mean to *converse* with them, to *connect* with them, or to *work with* and *motivate* them.  Your example sentence uses this last meaning.

> The grant is meant to inspire and **engage** young artists, to allow them to pursue their passion.

To "empower" someone is a relative recent (mid-1980s) expression meaning "to give someone the feeling of power and self-worth".

> The program helps **empower** children from disadvantaged families to complete their high school education and go on to get college degrees.

These can be used together in a more graceful way:

> Renowned Chinese singer and actor Wang Yuan ... will use his widespread influence to **engage and empower** children and young people, to strive to be best they can possibly be.

Of course, these can just be [buzzwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword) that *sound* nice but have have no real practical application.  Government announcements from any country often include bold proclamations but achieve unremarkable results.